# Cannot activate addon "Import Images as Planes"

Tags: add-on

In trying to experiment creating terrain using height maps, I have had difficulty getting the addon "using images as planes" to work. In frustration, I uninstalled my Blender and re-installed 2.79b. The addon does appear in the inport-export list, however when I try to activate it I get this error:

Report Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 324, in enable mod=_import_(module_name)
  File C:\Users\user\AppData|Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\scripts\addons\io_import_images_as_planes.py", line 1
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec 6 2015, 01:54:25)(MSC v.1900 64 bit)] on win32 
^
Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax
```

I can't seem to get around this. How do I activate this addon or what do I have to do to get around this problem.

Thanks, all

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, according to the traceback, your "io_import_images_as_planes.py" add-on file is corrupted. The line in question should be a comment not a procedure. This error alone can be easily fixed with putting one # character at beginning that line, like this.

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec 6 2015, 01:54:25)(MSC v.1900 64 bit)] on win32
```

to

```
#Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec 6 2015, 01:54:25)(MSC v.1900 64 bit)] on win32
```

However it most likely has other corruptions. My guess you got your add-on from the wrong place, because it should start with the line of

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
```

A possible solution:

Open the

```
C:\Users\user\AppData|Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\scripts\addons\io_import_images_as_planes.py
```

file with a text editor like notepad, delete everything.

Get the add-on from the github repository.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sambler/myblenderaddons/master/io_import_images_as_planes.py

Ctrl-a Ctrl-c to copy everything, and paste it in your notepad.

Than try to install it again.